# iis rewrite rule to ignore subdomain

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite rule to redirect none www to www and it works perfectly. but I want just to ignore the cdn subdomain so I added this rule above all other rules:

```
<rule name="Ignore cdn" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^static.mydomain.com" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="None" />
        </rule>
```

but it still redirects to www.mydomain.com. Isn't this code correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that might affect the rule (mainly the pattern itself):

```
<rule name="Ignore cdn" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^static\.mydomain\.com" />
      </conditions>
   <action type="None" />
</rule>
```

1. The main issue I see is the pattern - the dots in the url should be escaped.
2. The match url is generally used within a capture group (in this case it might not matter, although good habit for other rules).
3. If the changes above don't work you may need to actually just rewrite the url to itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I know that I should escape dots but I always forget it. alwaysssssss